# Project Euler #23

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop

I'm currently trying to solve the project euler problem number 23 :

> A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.
>
> A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.
>
> As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.
>
> Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

However my code is not giving correct result while it seems to be completely fine. Am I calculating more than the enough numbers ?

```
private static void Main()
    {
        List<int> AbudantNumbers = new List<int>();
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 12; i <= 28123; i++)
        {
            int abudantNumber = GetProperDivisor(i);
            if (abudantNumber > i)
            {
                AbudantNumbers.Add(i);
            }
        }

        for (int k = 1; k <= 28123; k++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < AbudantNumbers.Count; i++)
            {
                count = 0;
                if (AbudantNumbers[i] > k)
                {
                    break;
                }
                for (int j = i; j < AbudantNumbers.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (AbudantNumbers[j] > k)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (AbudantNumbers[i] + AbudantNumbers[j] == k)
                    {
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count == 0)
            {
                sum += k;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int GetProperDivisor(int input)
    {
        int sum = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= input / 2; i++)
        {
            if (input%i == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

My result is : 297632990
Correct result is : 4179871

Quite big difference when there are no obvious mistakes in my code.

My second approach :

```
        for (int k = 1; k <= 28123; k++)
        {
            var k1 = k;
            int count =
                (from t1 in AbudantNumbers.TakeWhile(t1 => t1 <= k1) let a = t1 select t1).Count(
                    t1 => AbudantNumbers.TakeWhile(t => t <= k).Any(t => t1 + t == k));
            if (count == 0)
            {
                sum += k;
            }
        }
```

My idea is to get all the abundant numbers lesser than 28123 than check all the integers lesser than 28123 (everything above have a sum of 2 abundant numbers) than rotate all the abundant numbers and lastly check if `abundantNumber1 + abundantNumber2 == currentNumber` if so we break out of the loop because we need only the ones that don't have a sum of 2 abundant numbers.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SpMdC1) of how I did it, maybe that will help you.

Comment: You are not taking numbers that can be written as the sum of the same abundant number out.  Try changing `int j = i + 1` in your `for` loop to `int j = i`  Also you are adding `k` to the `sum` inside of the first `for` loop over the abundant numbers, instead of outside of it.

Comment: It didn't change the output. However I noticed that the `break` after the `if(count==0)` prevents `i` from increasing right ?

Comment: Yeah, that's part of the problem.  Though I think this approach is going to result in NP complete code.  It's better to calculate all the abundant number sums to find the number that can be eliminated from the sum.

Comment: Updated the code a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find that the current number `k` is the sum of two abundant numbers `a[i] + a[j]`, you set the `count` and then break out of the loop – out of the inner loop over `j`, that is.

That means that you still consider all remaining `i`s, for which you reset the `count`. Effectively, you consider only the last abundant number that is smaller or equal to `k`. It is not likely that the sum of the two numbers involves this number, so your condition for adding the numbers, `count == 0` will be wrong in most cases.

You must break out of the two innermost loops when you find out that `k == a[i] + a[j]`. C# doesn't seem to have labelled loops, so it is probably best to refactor the the inner loops into a function that takes the list of abundant numbers and `k` as arguments; you can then simply return `true` when your condition is met.

As a quick but ugly fix, you can add

```
if (count) break;
```

after the loop over `j`.

Your approach is very ineffective, though. It might be better to write only two nested loops over all abundant numbers and then add their sums to a set when they are smaller than 28124. Then add all numbers from 1 to 28124 that are not in the set.